# Call contract that's unverified

Tags: abi, verify, frontend

I am currently developing a smart contract ecosystem. I want to interact with my smart contracts on the testnets. However, I have to verify to do so. I cannot verify, as I don't want my code displayed where anyone can see it.

**I will be calling my contracts from my localhost front end app**. Do you know of a method to call my smart contracts on testnet from a local frontend app without verifying the contracts? Thanks!

I know etherscan provides an ABI, but I need to be logged into my account to use it. Obviously won't be logged into my etherscan account when using my local host app.

Comment: how you compile and deploy contracts?

Comment: I compiled and deployed them using truffle. My front end app has truffle

Comment: then you should have ABI in your project. it should be in the build folder you can use that ABI wherever you want to.

Comment: I have the ABI and the address of my smart contracts, this means I can point all my requests at the address with web3 and it should work? I thought the code had to be verified to be used

Comment: Yes, you can do so although you will need to connect to the Ethereum node provider, I would recommend using https://infura.io/